# File response in asp.net core API

Tags: asp.net-core

I have searched many times for my problem but I couldn't find any solution.
the problem which faced is I wrote method yesterday in asp.net core API which is return file response as streaming video when I tried to test on my local machine it's working very well, but when uploading it to my VPS server I got the 500 internal server error so please what is the problem.
the following my code which I used:

```
[HttpPost("youtube")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetYoutubeVideoURL([FromBody] string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        return Ok(new { Error = "Please provide your url for fetch video." });
    }

    var id = YoutubeClient.ParseVideoId(url);

    if (id == null)
    {
        return Ok(new { Error = "Video id is not available, try again later." });
    }

    var client = new YoutubeClient(); //This should be initialized in YoutubeController constructor.
    var mediaInfoSet = await client.GetVideoMediaStreamInfosAsync(id);
    var mediaStreamInfo = mediaInfoSet.Audio.WithHighestBitrate();
    var mimeType = $"audio/{mediaStreamInfo.Container.GetFileExtension()}";
    var fileName = $"{id}.{mediaStreamInfo.Container.GetFileExtension()}";
    return File(await client.GetMediaStreamAsync(mediaStreamInfo), mimeType, fileName, true);
}
```